# C# How Do I Fix This Out Of Memory Exception?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, memory-management

I am writing a sample app that will display the current screenshot and also write it to an avi file continuously. I'm using SharpAvi for the avi writing. My problem is I'm getting this exception thrown:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Out of memory."

I think it has to do with The LockBits() method that I call, and the exception happens about 30 seconds after I run the application.

Here is my code that takes a screenshot:

```
public class Recording
{
//...
private void TakeScreenshot(byte[] buffer)
{
        using (var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(m_screenWidth, m_screenHeight))
        {
            using (var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(m_screenLeft, m_screenTop, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(m_screenWidth, m_screenHeight), System.Drawing.CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

                // Draw cursor.
                User32.CURSORINFO pci;
                pci.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(User32.CURSORINFO));

                if (User32.GetCursorInfo(out pci))
                {
                    if (pci.flags == User32.CURSOR_SHOWING)
                    {
                        User32.DrawIcon(g.GetHdc(), pci.ptScrenPos.x - m_screenLeft, pci.ptScrenPos.y - m_screenTop, pci.hCursor);
                        g.ReleaseHdc();
                    }
                }


                if (OnScreenCapture != null) 

                {
                    CaptureEventArgs args = new CaptureEventArgs(bitmap);
                    OnScreenCapture(this, args);
                }

                var bits = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle( // code breaks here
                    0,
                    0,
                    m_screenWidth,
                    m_screenHeight),
                    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
                Marshal.Copy(bits.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                bitmap.UnlockBits(bits);                
            }
        }
    }
}
public class CaptureEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource BitmapSource
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public CaptureEventArgs(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        BitmapSource = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
            IntPtr.Zero,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        BitmapSource.Freeze();
    } 
}
}
```

Here is my MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        m_recordTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        m_recordTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        m_recordTimer.Tick += recordTimer_Tick;

        m_stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        DataContext = this;

    }

    private void recordTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var elapsed = m_stopwatch.Elapsed;
        Elapsed = string.Format("{00:00}:{1:00}", Math.Floor(elapsed.TotalMinutes), elapsed.Seconds);
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartRecording();
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StopRecording();
    }

    private void StartRecording()
    {
        if(IsRecording)
        {
            return;
        }

        IsRecording = true;
        Elapsed = "00:00";
        IsLastScreenshot = false;

        m_stopwatch.Reset();
        m_recordTimer.Start();

        m_lastFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine("", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + ".avi");

        m_recorder = new Recording(m_lastFileName, KnownFourCCs.Codecs.MotionJpeg, 70, this);

        m_stopwatch.Start();

        m_recorder.OnScreenCapture += m_recorder_OnScreenCapture;
    }

    void m_recorder_OnScreenCapture(object sender, CaptureEventArgs e)
    {
        imgLive.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
        {
            imgLive.Source = e.BitmapSource;
        });
    }

    private void StopRecording()
    {
        if (!IsRecording)
        {
            return;
        }

        m_recorder.Dispose();
        m_recorder = null;
        m_recordTimer.Stop();
        m_stopwatch.Stop();
        IsRecording = false;
        IsLastScreenshot = true;
    }

    public bool IsRecording { get; private set; }

    public string Elapsed { get; private set; }

    public bool IsLastScreenshot { get; private set; }

    #region fields


    private DispatcherTimer m_recordTimer;
    private readonly Stopwatch m_stopwatch;
    private Recording m_recorder;
    private string m_lastFileName;
    #endregion

    internal void SetImage(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        imgLive.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
        {
            imgLive.Source = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
            IntPtr.Zero,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        });
    }
}
```

Let me know If I need to post more code; I am trying to show just what is needed. Also I should mention I'm not that experienced; I know just a little bit about threading and memory management. And I'll take suggestions for improvements.

Comment: did you get a stack trace?

Comment: My first thought is that you're not freeing up previous screenshots after they've been written to the avi. Look into that.

Comment: A quick glance over shows that you are disposing bitmaps through the use of "using" and you're freeing locked bits by unlocking them, so that's good. I'd suggest going into the debugger and checking the numbers for various parameters. Sometimes something goes wrong and you pass a 0 into the graphics systems for (say) height or width, which then results in an OOM exception.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Run a memory profiler on the program and take a few snapshots as it gets closer and closer to running out of memory. It might help show what resource is taking up all the space.

Comment: Thank you guys for your feedback. I just learned how to do a stack trace, and I never heard of a memory profiler before; but I'm learning about them now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have fixed my problem. Although I can't really explained it in great detail. All I did was change my CaptureEventArgs class to this:

```
public class CaptureEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public BitmapImage BitmapImage
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public CaptureEventArgs(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            memory.Position = 0;
            BitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            BitmapImage.BeginInit();
            BitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
            BitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            BitmapImage.EndInit();
            BitmapImage.Freeze();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm must of had a memory leak in here, and switching to a BitmapImage and using a MemoryStream type that gets disposed of after use fixed my problem.